# Sharepoint 2013 CMIS Workbench Login Fails with "One or more of the input parameters to the service method is missing or invalid"

Tags: sharepoint-2013, cmis, opencmis, cmis-workbench

Sharepoint 2013 CMIS Workbench Login Fails with "One or more of the input parameters to the service method is missing or invalid"

I have an install of Sharepoint 2013 and in the site settings I have enabled "Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) Producer".  I am using CMIS Workbench 0.9.0 (the latest at this time) to connect to the Sharepoint 2013 CMIS service.

I am logging in with this URL:

```
http://machinip:35382/cmis/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
```

When I click "Load Repositories" and I get a selection of 2 repositories to choose from: 1. "Administrative Report Library" 2. "Shared Document".  Regardless of which repository I pick, I get the following error: InvalidArgument: One or more of the input parameters to the serivce method is missing or invalid.

I have tried using the machine name instead of the IP address, and I receive the same error.

I also have an "Internal" url setup with the machine name and port as "default":

```
"http://machinename:35382"
```

I have authentication setup as "Basic".  I'll admit that I am not a Sharepoint expert.   I have also tried running workbench directly on the machine hosting SharePoint 2013 and still receive the same error.  I have also tried adding the machine name to the hosts file on the client running Workbench but that did not fix the problem.

I am able to connect to the InMemory server.  I have also successfully connected to a different machine running  SharePoint 2010.

Can someone help with this issue?  Are there other settings that need to be setup to make this work?

I found this issue that says an alternate mapping needs to be setup, but I believe I have one setup correctly already using the machine name.
     [Login error to Sharepoint 2013 repository using openCMIS Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611390/login-error-to-sharepoint-2013-repository-using-opencmis-workbench)

I have found this link and I am not sure if it applies.  If it does, how can I get around this issue?  If this is the problem, I would not be able to utilize the solution.
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-294

I receive the same error when I tried to connect to Sharepoint 2013 with my own application that works OK with the InMemory and SharePoint 2010 servers.

Here is the log from CMIS Workbench:

```
11:19:04 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: CmisInvalidArgumentException: One or more of the input parameters to the service method is missing or invalid.
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisInvalidArgumentException: One or more of the input parameters to the service method is missing or invalid.
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:423)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:554)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getTypeDefinitionInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:821)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getTypeDefinition(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getTypeDefinition(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getTypeDefinition(SessionImpl.java:518)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.model.ClientSession.createOperationContexts(ClientSession.java:244)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.model.ClientSession.createSession(ClientSession.java:195)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.LoginDialog$2.actionPerformed(LoginDialog.java:204)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2006)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2329)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:398)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:253)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:247)
11:19:04 ERROR hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: Error code: 0
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611390/login-error-to-sharepoint-2013-repository-using-opencmis-workbench

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you. Double check your Alternate Access Mapping Settings:

1. Go to the Central Administration page
2. Under System Settings, click  Configure Alternate Access Mappings
3. There should be at least two urls. One with server short name and one with server full name.
4. If the url is missing, click Add Internal Urls
5. For the Alternate Access Mapping Collection, click the No Selection link, change and select:

   - SharePoint - 80
   - Set the url such as   http://myserver.abc.xyz.com
   - Set  Zone: any such as Intranet
6. Click Save

(Note: I had posted the question that you had referenced and only finally had the time to get back to it)